# Reading bytes from a bin file and storing into a string with descriptor

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a string containing the value of the 4 bytes at position 424 as they appear in my Hex editor:
my hex editor displays 14583212 and I need a string containing "14583212"

This is the code that doesen't return anything but 000000:

```
- (NSString *) tcExtract: (NSString *) nomefile {

NSFileHandle *myFile= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:nomefile];
[myFile seekToFileOffset:424];
NSData *myData= [myFile readDataOfLength:4];
NSString *maxData= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04x", [myData description]];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your call to `[myData description]`.  That's giving you a string representing the hex value of the bytes.  Instead, get the bytes themselves into an integer, then format that as a string:

```
NSData *myData= [myFile readDataOfLength:4];
int myInt;
[myData getBytes:&myInt length:4];
NSString *maxData= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d", myInt];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you might run into endianness issues with this approach, since it's up to the CPU to interpret the sequence of bytes you read. You might as well end up with the bytes in the wrong order. I'd read the bytes as 4 individual `unsigned char`s and output them separately as `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]]`.

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work. I've also tryed to read only one byte at the time and the char approach. The weird thing is that from different files the software reads the same int value.... Thanks